# GroupBy date and time, orderBy date, and time AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to achieve this view here. From what I have it works great until an event occurs the next day, then the time order doesn't work, and also the events from next day are displayed after the one occurred previously. I'm using [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) to group my results
[image]

MyController

```
    $scope.histories = response.revision_history.map(function (data) {
        return {
            "date": data.created_at.substring(0,10),
            "time": data.created_at.substring(11,19),
            "user": data.user_id,
            "property": data.key,
            "old": data.old_value,
            "new": data.new_value
        }
    });
```

Jade

```
                                            .col-md-12(ng-repeat="history in histories | groupBy: 'date' | toArray: true")
                                                .crm-history-seperator
                                                    span {{ history[0].date }}
                                                .repeater(ng-repeat="event in history | groupBy: 'time' | toArray: true")
                                                    span.time {{ event[0].time }}
                                                    .repeater(ng-repeat="ev in event")
                                                        .content
                                                            .activity
                                                                span.user {{ ev.user }}
                                                                span.explanation Changed {{ ev.property }}
                                                                span.explanation(ng-if="ev.old !== null") from
                                                                span.event(ng-if="ev.old !== null") {{ ev.old }}
                                                                span.explanation to
                                                                span.event {{ ev.new }}
```

Here is what I get if some event happens the next day

[image]

Here is what I want to achieve

[image]

Comment: Frankly I didn't get what u r trying to convey.May be posting **actual output** and **desired output** would help. I once used `underscore.js` for such thing , and it was very easy to implement. http://underscorejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

From what I've concluded, order by is not working in your case. I think your answer lies between the way `groupBy` and `orderBy` expects arguments. Have a look at below answer.

https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/issues/57#issuecomment-65041792